# Regexp to match path in presence of sub path

Tags: python, regex

I have a fixed parent directory `/home/user`, the input can be:

```
/home/user
/home/user/
/home/user/foo
/home/user/foo/
/home/user/foo/bar
....
```

I want to match everything except the first two paths. Any idea on how to do that?

I came up with https://regex101.com/r/75lrkL/1 but I need to remove the second match and add the last one.

```
/home/user/([^/]+)
```

Comment: Rather than deleting your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78012202/regexp-to-match-input-if-subdirectory-is-present) and asking a new identical question you should have edited the old question to add the extra details.  The old and new look the same except the new one has a link to an offsite webpage. Any regex you use should be included in the question, the offsite link is just an optional extra.

Comment: What is random or unhelpful about my comment? I was merely trying to help you understand the rules of this site. Perhaps you should take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to better understand how this site works.

Comment: The unhelpful thing was posting a link to what is regexp when someone asking about a specific question means they already know. If someone asks about python you aren't going to link the entire python docs and imply "figure it out"

Comment: Also the site doesn't let me post regexp questions in this tag unless I have a link to one of the popular demo sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
^/home/user(?=/\w).+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GPbRSK/1)

The `(?=/\w)` pattern is a lookahead assertion. It checks to see if the next character is a forward slash followed by a character. It means it doesn't accept the first two. Next, you get the rest of the path.

Since you included the Python tag:

```py
import re

pattern = r"^/home/user(?=/\w).+$"
paths = [
    "/home/user",
    "/home/user/",
    "/home/user/foo",
    "/home/user/foo/",
    "/home/user/foo/bar",
]
for path in paths:
    match_object = re.match(pattern, path)
    if match_object:
        print(match_object.group())
```

Comment: This will fail for path elements that don't happen to start with an alphanumeric character (e.g. "*/home/user/.dotfile*"). But in any case, there's really no need to use regexps for a task like this, since the functionality is already provided by the stdlib: `import fnmatch; fnmatch.filter(paths, '/home/user/?*')`.

Comment: The anchor `$` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an negated character class `[^/]+` that can also match a newline, that is why you are also matching the second line in your example data.

If you want to match the last 2 lines and not match 2 consecutive forward slashes, you can use:

```
^/home/user(?:/[^/\n]+)+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `/home/user` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `/[^/\n]+` Match `/` followed by 1 or more characters other than `/` or a newline
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o92T2G/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/61wzew)

Or a simpler version that allows one or more times any character after the `/`

```
^/home/user/.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jjVDU8/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^/home/user(?:/[^/\n]+)+"

s = ("/home/user\n"
    "/home/user/\n"
    "/home/user/foo\n"
    "/home/user/bar/foo")
    
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['/home/user/foo', '/home/user/bar/foo']
```

Comment: I've noticed you've been orbiting the black hole "regex", picking up speed of late. Don't forget that once you get pulled in there's no way out. I've seen it happen to others and it ain't pretty.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I got pulled in, I think I just saw Elvis.

Answer (score 1):

If `'home'` and `'user'` are merely placeholders you could match

```
^\/(?:[^/\r\n]+\/){2}.+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GOI5So/1)

Breakdown:

```
^            # match the beginning of the string
\/           # match '/'
(?:          # begin a non-capture group
  [^/\r\n]+  # match one or more characters other than '/' and line terminators
  \/         # match '/'
){2}         # end the non-capture group and execute it twice
.+           # match the rest of the line, excluding line terminators
```